# How to prevent NegativeScreen from making Point N Click flicker?

Tags: windows-7, accessibility, dwell-clicker

[NegativeScreen](https://archive.org/details/negative-screen) makes [Point-N-Click virtual mouse](http://www.polital.com/pnc/) ([mirror](https://archive.org/details/point-n-click-virtual-mouse))'s window flickers:

[image]

How to prevent Negative Screen from  making Point N Click flicker?

I use Windows 7 SP1 x64 Ultimate.